# XmlSerialize an Enum Flag field

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, xml-serialization

I have this :

```
    [Flags]
    public enum InfoAbonne{civilite,name,firstname,email,adress,country }

    public class Formulaire
    {
      private InfoAbonne _infoAbonne{ get; set;}
      public Formulaire()
      {}
    }
```

I want to Xml serialize Formulaire

If I init :
`_infoAbonne = InfoAbonne.name | InfoAbonne.email;`

In my Xml Result I get only :

```
<InfoAbonne>email</InfoAbonne>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though you added the `Flags` attribute to your enum, you still need to make sure that the values are powers of two:

```
[Flags]
public enum InfoAbonne
{
    civilite = 1,
    name = 2,
    firstname = 4,
    email = 8,
    adress = 16,
    country = 32
}
```

See the guidelines laid out in the **Remarks** section of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx).

Comment: Ok it work but is it normal I get <InfoAbonne>civilite email</InfoAbonne> my two values with a space between?

Comment: +1 for simplicity and MSDN reference. Although 11:1 upvotes ratio from your to my answer is a bit much! Nevermind ;)

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson: Agreed. The reason for this might be that you put your focus on the serialization part and only later added the part that solved the underlying problem.

Comment: @ChristopheDebove: It seems to be normal, I get the same result. I find it odd, because `ToString` on a variable like this returns them with a comma in between...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yes I edited it in - to be fair I didn't see your answer before submitting the edit. Anyway c'est la vie on SO ;) I still gave yours +1 since it was more consise. Regarding ToString returning a comma, might be culture variant? Serializing an *int32* might not be pretty but is guaranteed to work across cultures and other quirks. I've also used this method to reduce XML file size

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson: I didn't say you copied that part of your answer :) What I meant was: When you edited that part in, my answer already was ahead 3 or 4 upvotes. And you know how they say: "rep goes to rep"... Anyway, I agree about serializing the int instead of the strings, if the serializing is merely about persisting the object. However, if it is reused, maybe displayed using XSLT, I would go with the string, because the numbers are not as expressive.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth No worries at all mate - I wasn't inferring anything!! Good point about XSLT & rendering of the serialized value btw.

Comment: @ChristopheDebove (much much later), the reason the values are serialized with a space between them is that that is the separator for XML Schema lists (in a simple type) and the serializer authors picked that as the best mapping for multiple values.

Answer (score 8):

The basic idea with these sorts of problems is to serialize a backing field which mimics the field you want to serialize. Same principle can be applied to complex types such as Bitmaps etc... For instance, instead of serializing the Enum field directly, you could serialize a backing field of type int:

```
// Disclaimer: Untested code, both in execution and compilation
[Flags]      
public enum InfoAbonne 
{
    civilite = 0x1, // Increment each flag value by *2 so they dont conflict
    Name=0x2,
    firstname=0x4,
    email=0x8,
    adress=0x10,
    country=0x20 
}  

// Don't serialize this property
[XmlIgnore]
private InfoAbonne _infoAbonne { get; set;} 

// Instead serialize this property as integer
// e.g. name | email will equal 0xA in hex, or 10 in dec
[XmlElement("InfoAbonne")]
public int InfoAbonneSerializer 
{ 
    get { return (int)_infoAbonne; } 
    set { _infoAbonne= (InfoAbonne) value; } 
}
```

Best regards,

Comment: I don't understand why you're using an InfoAbonneSerializer. I don't want the int value.

Comment: @ChristopheDebove Hi there. The Serializer field wraps the actual field you want to expose in your domain object, allowing it to be serialized correctly. It doesn't really matter what the value is in the XML file, so long as it persists and can be reloaded.

Comment: Andrew Burnett-Thompson ok, but I doesn't need to deserialize but I use it for xslt transformation so enum "text" value is more interresting for me. But Thank you

Comment: @ChristopheDebove as you tested Daniels answer and it worked, you don't need the serializer field. I wasn't aware that simply setting the power of two values on flags would allow it to serialize. The solution I presented above has helped me out before with complex types such as Bitmaps or Nullable<T>

Answer (score 0):

Dr. ABT's answer is better than the selected answer. Yes, having values in powers of 2 is necessary, but that isn't specific to XML Serialization issues.

Enums are serialized very differently than most objects. Enums will be XML Serialized by their name (`ser(MyEnumProperty.[Name]) = "[Name]"`) instead of using the value of name (`ser(MyEnumProperty.[Name]) = 8`).

```
// Version 1.0
[Flags]      
public enum MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    All = First | Second
}

public MyEnum MyEnumProperty = MyEnum.All;
```

If you were to serialize `MyEnumProperty`, you would get `<MyEnum>`**`All`**`</MyEnum>`. However, if you serialized `(int)MyEnumProperty`, you would get `<int>`**`3`**`</int>`. I'd like to mention why this is incredibly necessary to know...

```
// Version 2.0
[Flags]      
public enum MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 4, // <---
    All = First | Second | Third
}
```

I've added new Enum values, which might have been used (as a DLL) in other projects. Oh wow... what are these errors?

**You can no longer deserialize your newest version of the enum to an older version with XML Serialization ([Binary Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233836(v=vs.90).aspx) should still work)!**

Take a look at the [ToEnum](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/R/0ac7f5da792ebc72.html) method by Microsoft. This prevents an ID (say, "Third" in the updated enum) from being looked at because it doesn't exist in the original enum. Also note that an error will be thrown which could break your project if it's not handled.

Be safe, always serialize and deserialize by value when given the chance. This is why we use objects like flagged enums to begin with. Objects like flagged enums reduce backwards compatibility and dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Flags]
public enum InfoAbonne
{
    civilite = (1 << 0),
    name = (1 << 1),
    firstname = (1 << 2),
    email = (1 << 3),
    adress = (1 << 4),
    country = (1 << 5)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider adding a little explanation as to how this solves the OP's question.